# Solving $a$, $b$, and $c$ in $y = a \times b^{cx}$ given three unique $x,y$ points

Tags: systems-of-equations, exponential-function

Given three unique points $(x_1, y_1)$, $(x_2, y_2)$, and $(x_3, y_3)$ on the line $y = a b^{cx}$, how would I solve for the parameters $a$, $b$, and $c$?  I'm hoping that there is only one solution.

I've already found $a$ with substitution:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\frac{ab^{cx_1}}{ab^{cx_2}} &= \frac{y_1}{y_2} \\\\
\frac{b^{cx_1}}{b^{cx_2}} &= \frac{y_1}{y_2} \\\\
b^{(cx_1-cx_2)} &= y_1 / y_2 \\\\
\therefore b &= (y_1/y_2)^{(cx_1-cx_2)^{-1}} \\\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

Substituting that into the original equation:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
a \cdot ( (y_1/y_2)^{(cx_1-cx_2)^{-1}} ) ^{cx_1} &= y_1 \\\\
a \cdot ( y_1/y_2 )^{x_1/(x_1-x_2)} &= y_1
\end{split}
\end{equation}

$$
\therefore a = \frac{y_1}{( y_1/y_2 )^{x_1/(x_1-x_2)}}\quad \text{(not very Q.E.D.)}
$$

This lets me state that $b^{cx_1} = \frac{y_1}{a}$ etc., but to solve $b$ and $c$ eludes me, and I'm not entirely sure there's one single solution.

Comment: We have $b^{cx}=(b^2)^{\frac{c}{2}x}=(b^c)^x$ and so on, so there is no unique solution for $(b, c)$.

Answer (score 1):

The values of $b$ and $c$ here are not independent. Write $b^{cx}=e^{rx}$ by defining

$$r=c\log b$$

where I will write all logs to base $e$. Then you have $y=ae^{rx}$, so there are two independent parameters, not three. This means that in general three points may not all lie on one curve of this form. The equations read

\begin{align*}
    y_1&=ae^{rx_1}\\
    y_2&=ae^{rx_2}\\
    y_3&=ae^{rx_3}\\
    &\iff\\
    \log y_1&=\log a+rx_1\\
    \log y_2&=\log a+rx_2\\
    \log y_3&=\log a+rx_3\\
\end{align*}
This system has a solution if and only if $x_i\ne x_j$ for some $(i,j)$ and
$$(x_1-x_2)(\log y_2-\log y_3)=(x_2-x_3)(\log y_1-\log y_2)$$
In this case, the solution is given by

\begin{align*}
    r&=\frac{\log y_i-\log y_j}{x_i-x_j}\\
    a&=y_1e^{-rx_1}
\end{align*}

If you want to write these in terms of $b,c$, then as noted in a comment, $b,c$ are not uniquely determined. Given $r$, if you choose any $b>0$ then you can define $c=r/\log b$.